# SSRS: Need Count of Actual Rows in Report

Tags: reporting-services

I have a Text Box in the Footer section of my report with the following expression:

```
= " Total Loans: " & CountRows("MyDatasetName") & "."
```

This returns a value that is not the exact number of rows displayed on the report [I manually counted]. There are 30 rows in the report - and the Total Loans reported by my expression is 34.

What I would REALLY like to do is get a count of the rows that are displayed in the report.

If I run the SQL for the Dataset in SSMS - I get 34 rows.

??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Silly question - does your report run to a second page?  I assume you've not manually applied any filter to strip out those 4 extra rows.  Without seeing the data (or an example of both present and missing data) it's difficult to know what could be causing the problem

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that your table has a grouping or filter that is limiting your returned rows from 34 to 30.  That being said, it doesn't matter why it's limited as you are looking to do a table row count from outside of the table.

I would try adding an additional, hidden column in the table that has an expression in the header cell (not within a row group) like:

```
=CountRows()
```

This will return the number of rows in your table, albeit hidden in an invisible column.  Now in your footer, create an expression which directly references the previously created textbox in the table like:

```
=ReportItems!TextBox1.Value
```

Your other option is to recreate the logical number of rows through an expression.  For example, if you have a row grouping on a field called country and you only have 30 distinct counties in your dataset of 34 rows.  Then the logical rowcount would be the number of distinct countries:

```
=CountDistinct(Fields!Country.Value, "Dataset1")
```